# Alter Table Primary key - Crate DB

Tags: cratedb

I want to alter a table in my **Crate DB** to change the primary key constraint to add a column to the existing one. If I need to drop the constraint and create a new one what would be the SQL syntax for the same. I have been trying the conventional SQL syntax and it does not seem to work:

```
alter table my_data_table drop primary key;
```

the above command gives an error:

```
SQLActionException[SQLParseException: line 1:34: no viable alternative at input 'alter table my_data_table drop']
```

I checked the Alter table SQL reference and can only find ways to add columns but nothing about altering the constraints.So if you are aware of how to do this, please let me know. 
cheers!

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: its a Crate DB http://crate.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no way to alter the primary key once a table has been created. You need to create a new table that has the schema you'd like to have and then either move the data over with `COPY TO` and `COPY FROM` or with `insert into to_table (i) (select ... from t)`. With CrateDB > 2.0 it's also possible to rename tables, so you can still use the original table name.

Answer (score -1):

First use the following code snippets for finding the constraints

```
SELECT Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col WHERE 
       Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
       AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
       AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND Col.Table_Name = '<your table name>'
```

Then use this to drop the constraint

```
ALTER TABLE Customer DROP CONSTRAINT Constraint_Name;
```

P.S: considering you are using SQL SERVER

Comment: thank you, but I'm using a Crate DB and not SQL Server, this wont work on it.

Comment: From [documentaion](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/sql/reference/constraints.html), "Adding a PRIMARY KEY column is only possible if the table is empty."
If your table doesn't contain any data yet, you can easily update your table creation command. If the table has content, then sorry you cannot change primary key (but can add another column ([using alter table](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/sql/reference/alter_table.html))).