# Why Alter Table Primary key is not possible - Crate DB

Tags: sql, cratedb

I can't find any info about dropping primary key in documentation of cratedb but we can drop CHECK constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE table_ident DROP CONSTRAINT check_name
```

below link says -there is no way to delete Primary KEY.
[Alter Table Primary key - Crate DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265054/alter-table-primary-key-crate-db)
I wanted to understand the reason behind this. Why it is not supported?

Comment: Best practice alone says that every table should have a defined primary key.  So, even it your DB would allow this, it wouldn't be engendering good table/database design.

Comment: what if we need to switch the PK? suppose we have column 'A' as PK in some table now i want another column (let's say 'B') as PK.